# Memory requirement for LAPACK dorgqr routine

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, lapack

I want to implement my own version of the dorgqr function in LAPACK to find Q matrix in QR factorization for a tall skinny matrix A (mxn). To compute even reduced Q, we would need an identity matrix of size mxm. For an over determined system, this can result in a large amount of memory.

But the API only requires an additional scratch memory; "WORK" that has size of n (number of columns). This is much less than the identity matrix that would have to be initialized for it to work. Can somebody please explain how the API is able to work without allocating mxm scratch memory?